# i need a script to make the header images change every 10 seconds or so?

Tags: php, html, header

i know a little php. Can anyone tell me how to write a simple php script so that the image in the header changes every 5 seconds or so. I dont want to place any kind of links on that image just want to change the images . thank you :))

Comment: Do you mean change once per load, or dynamically all the time people are viewing the page? The latter is JavaScript, not PHP.

Comment: Just another showme hte scriptz question. Where is your attempt?

Comment: looks like a script request to me... look to javascript! (ie. jquery/jcarousel plugin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP can only *provide* the image, you need a little bit of JavaScript to trigger events fetching the new images.

Here's a way to do it, adapted from http://javascript.internet.com/miscellaneous/random-image-rotator.html:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>

<!-- STEP ONE: The core of it: JavaScript... -->

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- Original:  Robert Bui (astrogate@hotmail.com) -->
<!-- Web Site:  http://astrogate.virtualave.net -->

<!-- Begin
var interval = 2.5; // delay between rotating images (in seconds)
var random_display = 1; // 0 = no, 1 = yes
interval *= 1000;

var image_index = 0;
image_list = new Array();
image_list[image_index++] = new imageItem("http://www.something.com/image01.jpg");
image_list[image_index++] = new imageItem("http://www.something.com/image02.jpg");
image_list[image_index++] = new imageItem("http://www.something.com/image03.jpg");
image_list[image_index++] = new imageItem("http://www.something.com/image04.jpg");
var number_of_image = image_list.length;
function imageItem(image_location) {
    this.image_item = new Image();
    this.image_item.src = image_location;
}
function get_ImageItemLocation(imageObj) {
    return(imageObj.image_item.src)
}
function generate(x, y) {
    var range = y - x + 1;
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * range) + x;
}
function getNextImage() {
    if (random_display) {
        image_index = generate(0, number_of_image-1);
    } else {
        image_index = (image_index+1) % number_of_image;
    }
    var new_image = get_ImageItemLocation(image_list[image_index]);
    return(new_image);
}
function rotateImage(place) {
    var new_image = getNextImage();
    document[place].src = new_image;
    var recur_call = "rotateImage('"+place+"')";
    setTimeout(recur_call, interval);
}
//  End -->
</script>
</HEAD>

<!-- STEP TWO: Insert the onLoad event handler into your BODY tag  -->

<BODY OnLoad="rotateImage('rImage')">

<!-- STEP THREE: Copy this code into the BODY of your HTML document  -->

<center>
<img name="rImage" src="http://www.something.com/image01.jpg" width=120 height=90>
</center>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: i dot know javascript at all. can i still use it?

Comment: @Danny: Hot Tip: Learn Javascript!

Comment: @Danny: Nope, you can't use it, because then your site will totally fail since the script is tightly connected to your knowledge. So, start learning a little JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for copying the code here. I clarified it a bit. @Danny: If you're having trouble with it, just start with copying the code into a plain html-file and work your way from there.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't know a huge amount about PHP I'm afraid but here is a good little script I found written in javascript that may help you:

http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1012

Hope that helps at all.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Image Rotate
  </head>

  <body>
  <img src="" name="Rotating" id="Rotating1" width=100 height=100>
  <img src="" name="Rotating" id="Rotating2" width=100 height=100>


  <script language="JavaScript">
  var ImageArr1 = new Array("Picture(3).jpg","Picture(1).jpg","Picture(2).jpg");
  var ImageHolder1 = document.getElementById('Rotating1');

  var ImageArr2 = new Array("Picture(5).jpg","Picture(6).jpg","Picture(7).jpg");
  var ImageHolder2 = document.getElementById('Rotating2');

  function RotateImages(whichHolder,Start)
  {
    var a = eval("ImageArr"+whichHolder);
    var b = eval("ImageHolder"+whichHolder);
    if(Start>=a.length)
        Start=0;
    b.src = a[Start];
    window.setTimeout("RotateImages("+whichHolder+","+(Start+1)+")",1500);
  }

  RotateImages(1,0);
  RotateImages(2,0);

  </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```